# Facebook login silently failing

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to implement login to a website with Facebook, using their JavaScript SDK.  I understand that this is OAuth 2 under the hood, although that shouldn't even matter...  I am setting things up using the async loader, and the FB variable exists and I can call functions in it.  When I call FB.login(), another tab opens, flashes for a fraction of a second, and then closes.  I then wind up back on my page, with no events having been triggered and no sign that anything has happened.

I have initialized the API as follows:

```
FB.init({
    appId      : facebookAppID,
    channelUrl : channelFilePath,
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log("Connected.");
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log("Not logged in.");
    } else {
        console.log("Still not logged in.");
    }
});
```

Then my login call is simply:

```
function loginFacebook() {
    console.log("Trying to log in.");
    FB.login();
}
```

One detail which might be relevant is that I'm running for development purposes on a nonstandard port, 1980 instead of 80.  It's not easy for me to try port 80, because of where I'm running, but if it turns out to be the problem I absolutely can.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Additionally, I did check and we're not in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the port.  Yes - they check, apparently!  The completely silent failure was really perplexing...